# google app engine: how to add information to the connect/disconnect channel "ping"s?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, channel

I enabled channel presence in google app engine, so I get a "ping" whenever a client connects/disconnects a channel. This is great! However, it's not enough. I would like additional information. For example: which page the client is on (i.e., the uri the client sees), or additional JS variables.

I didn't find any mention of this on google's tutorials. How do I do this, and is it even possible?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible for technical reasons -- the server generating those requests has no knowledge of the state of the client. If you want that data for connect, though, you could manually POST (to a different URL) when you get the onopen callback.

Comment: Thanks! Is this due for implementation anytime?

Comment: No, it's not. It would be very difficult to implement.